# Access A/D converter using spidev in Python

Tags: python, spi

I'm working on a project where I want to collect a voltage input using the 24 bit ADS1211U A/D converter and a Raspberry pi 2 model B.

I've installed the latest spidev module in python 3 and according to the datasheet of the A/D I'm supposed to send one byte to instruct the A/D what I want (to read from the data output register) and then read three bytes (24 bits of information).

My code is as follows:

```
import spidev
from time import sleep

# Open SPI bus
spi = spidev.SpiDev()
spi.open(0,0)

sleepTime = 0.5

def readADC():
    spi.writebytes([128]) # send '10000000' to read from DOR
    rawData = spi.readbytes(3) # read 24 bits of information
    print(rawData)

try:
    while True:
        readADC()
        sleep(sleepTime)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    spi.close()
```

After connecting the MOSI -> MOSI, MISO -> MISO, CLK -> CLK and CS -> CE0, as well as power and GND, I don't seem to get any reading of significance. All I get is 24 zeroes when I run the program.

Is there something essential I've missed regarding the spidev module or *should* it work only I've messed up the wiring somehow?

The datasheet of the ADS1211U can be found here: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/sbas034b/sbas034b.pdf

Sorry if I didn't articulate the problem enough, I'll gladly give more information if needed.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: spi not required `speed` or IC need `external clock` ?